# How to execute huge SQL queries rapidly with EFCore?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here are two simplified examples of SQL queries I recently run on my SQL database:

```
insert into new_entity
select top 10000 field1,
                 field2
from old_entity
```

&

```
update top 1000 e
            set field1 = 13
           from entity e
          where field1 is null
```

Their execution was so fast it's barely noticeable.

However, if I want to perform the same operation using EF, the way I know would be iterating over each object:

```
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
  var new_objs = db.old_entity.Take(10000).Select(ot=> new new_entity() { ... });
  db.new_entity.AddRange(new_objs);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

&

```
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
  var objs = db.entity.Where(e => e.field1 == null).Take(1000);
  objs.ForEach(e => e.field1 = 13);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Which lasted for hours, which is unacceptable.

I can execute a raw SQL query from within the app, but for real-life complex objects, it's a dradgery.

Is there a way to code such operations using the EF model with a performance of a directly written query?

Comment: `Which lasted for hours, which is unacceptable.` which part lasted for hours? The read or the update?

Comment: @JamesGould the update. Otherwise it would be a different problem ;)

Comment: The simple answer is when your favourite tool is a hammer, don't forget that you have an entire toolbelt at your disposal. You'd don't have to view every problem as if it were a nail. Massive bulk operations that do not require nor benefit from loading and tracking entire rows in memory should not involve loading and tracking entire rows in memory. EF is the hammer, you should consider a saw if you want to cut that 2x4. It can technically be done with a hammer, but nowhere near the best option.

Comment: Take a look at EFCore.BulkExtensions (nuget). Amazing performance on large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 7 have introduced new method `ExecuteUpdate`. And your query for update can be written in the following way:

```cs
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
    var objs = db.entity.Where(e => e.field1 == null).Take(1000);
    objs.ExecuteUpdate(b => b.SetProperty(x => x.field1, x => 13));
}
```

INSERT FROM is not supported by EF Core any versions.

Anyway, you can install third-party extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), note that i'm one of the creators.

**Insert**

```cs
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
    var new_objs = db.old_entity.Take(10000).Select(ot=> new new_entity() { ... });

    new_objs.Insert(db.new_entity.ToLinqToDBTable());
}
```

**Update**

```cs
using(var db = new myDbContext())
{
    var objs = db.entity.Where(e => e.field1 == null).Take(1000);

    objs
      .Set(x => x.field1, x => 13)
      .Update();
}
```